# How get views advanced dynamic URL contextual filter to work with full taxonomy path?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I've tried all settings, with joint paths etc...but I just can't get the filter working properly, I know it's a settings thing, watched a whole bunch of videos but can't put my finger on it!

This is for advanced contextual filter, the dynamic one that can change depending on URL, not the static one.

Like this:

```
Animals
-Pets
-Farm
```

Path is:

```
localhost/animals/pets/cats.htm
localhost/animals/farm/cows.htm
```

I would like the filter ***animals/pets*** to show cats.htm content

I would like the filter ***animals/farm*** to show cow.htm content

I can get the filter working with single taxonomies, but not with full path.

**animals** works, but not **animals/farm** and not **animals/pets**

Attaching an image with the screen where I should set this up

[image]

Comment: Filter is dynamic, not the static one on left. It acts like a variable or a token, one in advanced settings. The .htm path is just for example sake

Comment: A sceenshot of your complete view configuration would be helpful as well. Also, Drupal (and especially views) do not work with HTML pages, so how do you want to show cats.htm content?

Comment: HTML is just for the example, not using .html suffix, that was just to distinguish the element as destination item, and not category name.  Near giving up on this, I don't think it's even possible!

Comment: You may implement HOOK_views_pre_view or HOOK_views_query_alter using your custom module to override the contextual filter with a custom value as you like. You can use something like arg(0) to read the URL.

Answer (score 4):

You must use 2 contextual filters

[image]

First one is: Contextual filter: Content: Has taxonomy term ID depth modifier

[image]

Second one is: Contextual filter: Content: Has taxonomy term ID depth modifier with the same criteria you did.

[image]

I put the view path to be the vocabulary name and tested contextual filters like:

```
//Hierarichay
      tag1
        tag2
        tag2

//Urls
    tag1/tag2
    tag1/tag3
```

The views gets results for the child tags every time {2, 3}.
If you didn't use the first filter it will consider the parent as argument.

Hope it solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks but now working still, what do I put for these settings? Depth
Allow multiple values
Set the breadcrumb for the term parents
Display all results for the specified field
 Provide default value
 Show "Page not found"
 Display a summary
 Display contents of "No results found"
 Display "Access Denied"
Skip default argument for view URL

Comment: Display all results

Comment: Thanks Mohammed, but not working...tried almost every possible settings and combinations, days trying now;(

Comment: It depends on you site configurations, taxonomy terms hierarchy and content relations, more information it may help.

Comment: Site for testing is over here:  http://xuzo.com/a1test/  I sent you an email mohammed, whoever can figure this out will be my hero!